# Управление и просмотр фоновых задач в Debian

Tags: linux, debian

В Linux существуют утилиты jobs - для просмотра фоновых задач, fg - для перетаскивания задачи на передний план, и bg - для перевода задачи в фоновой режим. 
Сколько не искал,не могу найти пакеты этих утилит для дистрибутива Debian. Не подскажите, какие аналоги для этих команд есть для Debian ?

Answer (score 2):

Эти команды (`bg`, `fg`, `jobs`) являются *встроенными командами оболочки* (*shell builtin command*) т.е. они интерпретируются непосредственно самой оболочкой (обычно `bash`) и для них не существует отдельных исполняемых файлов. Соответственно никакому пакету они принадлежать не могут, а также невозможно тривиально вызвать их с помощью `exec ()`.

См. [соответствующую секцию](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=bash&category=1&russian=2#lbCZ) в `man bash`.

Comment: Почему тогда на Ubuntu при вызове команды jobs  показывает список задач,а на Debian пишет - команда не найдена.

Comment: @Wizardddd, нет никаких причин, почему это могло бы так быть... все объяснения, которые я моу дать сводятся «ты что-то не так делаешь» (со спектром от опечатки, до используешь какой-то другой, крайне странный, шелл).